Can't configure correctly mitmproxy in transparent mode on macos
I want to see the traffic of some devices that don't support proxied connections and am trying to configure my iMac (Catalina) as a wifi hotspot with port forwarding to a mitmproxy in transparent mode. I followed the mitmproxy documentation with no luck.
So to sum up what I did, I firstly shared my internet connection. My iMac is connected to my internet box by ethernet, and my test devices connect to the iMac by wifi (i'm doing the configuration with my phone). This step is OK. In plane mode with active wifi and connected to the iMac, I can browse the internet.
Next, mitmproxy documentation says to activate port forwarding. Done.
Next, the rdr rule, specifying that the interface en0 they quoted in their example must be "replaced with the interface on which your test device will appear". Ok, executing ifconfig, I can see the en0 is my ethernet connection (it has my local ip 192.168.1.xx) while en1 seems to be my wifi hotspot, with an autoassigned IP (169.254.83.217). My guess is to set the rule like this, right?
rdr pass on en1 inet proto tcp to any port {80, 443} -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080

So using en1, my wifi hotspot. I placed this rule directly into /etc/pf.conf just after the line rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
I also configured the sudoers, and everyone is able to execute sudo pfctl -s state with no password. At this point, I can see my phone is correctly accessing to remote servers through my iMac.
But as soon as I enable the rdr rule (with mitmproxy started in transparent mode), I loose my internet connection on my mobile. Wifi is still working, I'm still seeing my iMac (ping is responsive), but mitm.it can't be found and I can't see internet anymore. And not because DNS are not accesible (they aren't, ping is not OK), but access is just denied. I can't access a local website hosted on my iMac using ip:port neither, even if the ping is ok. Disabling pfctl doesn't help, I have to shutdown the connection sharing and enable it again to get my connection back, not redirected to my mitmproxy. I deduce pf is blocking the traffic, but my very limited knowledge about pf and firewalls as a general rule avoid me to find a solution...
I saw several posts about this: in some case some answers say to add the 8080 port, other  suggests to remove "pass" from the rule, ... Well, nothing worked, that's why I created another post, trying to figure what's happening in my particular case.
Thanks
